Adding comment and formatting with REST API for Azure Devops
I'd like to add formatted comment on a work item with REST API in PowerShell.
I tried this :
$comment = [System.Net.WebUtility]::HtmlEncode(" Here is a new file with relevant information: $DDJ Relevant Information #@$%^&*")

$commentwithmention = "<div><a href="#">@User</a>$comment</div>" #9c48ef54-c54b-6049-98ab-982453ed3e4c

$body = @{
    "text" = $commentwithmention
} | ConvertTo-Json

The comment itself worked ! but i can't format the text. I'd like to add formatting, strong and italics on the $DDJ Relevant Information
The HTML balises are not interpreted, event with the HTML encoding.
Is this possible?

HTML-encode the different parts of the string separately, then add the HTML tags after

Have you tried using markdown instead of HTML?

In fact, it was the HtmlEncode that caused this. I had some special characters to encode, which is why it happened. (Sorry, I forgot to mention it earlier.) I just removed HtmlEncode and encoded the variable with UTF-8, and it worked.

I have tested the script sample and reproduced the same issue.
The cause of the issue could be that the special characters(e.g.#) will change the format of the HTML code.
To solve this issue, you can use 'code' to replace "code" in the $commentwithmention.
Here is an example:
$token = "PAT"

$commentwithmention = '<div><a href="#">@User</a><strong>This text is important!</strong></div>'

$url=" https://dev.azure.com/xx/xx/_apis/wit/workItems/xx/comments?api-version=7.0-preview.3"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$body = @{
    "text" = $commentwithmention
} | ConvertTo-Json
echo $body
$response3 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method POST -Body $body -ContentType application/jsoN

Result:

